# Iframe facebook video embed does not work on mobile devices

Tags: facebook, iframe

Hello I use this code on my website to display facebook vidéo :

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=XX" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Probleme : it does not work on mobile devices (it requiered impossible fash payer instalation)

It tried using the facebook tool to integrate a video post on a website :
http://nsa34.casimages.com/img/2013/10/17/131017070157521369.png
Exemple :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> <script>(function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=589822344439680" data-width="550"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=589822344439680">Publication</a> de <a href="https://www.facebook.com/AmazingCrazyVideos">Amazing and Crazy videos</a>.</div></div>
```

This one work great but it does not only dispay the video..
I just need the vidéo

I tried this :

```
<object width="400" height="224" > 
 <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /> 
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /> 
 <param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/xxx" /> 
 <embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/xxx" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  
   allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="400" height="224"> 
 </embed> 
</object>
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 1):

this is the code I use... you only change the video video_id=628132747223650 and he Heigth and width and thats it

```
    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=628132747223650" height="320" width="540" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the video to be correctly sized within a div, just set the width 100%.
Example:

`<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=785565964819891" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

try to increase z-index of iframe it works for me.